# Parsing json data to typescript class

Tags: json, typescript

I am receiving JSON  from the request and I need to cast it to my typescrypt class which you can see below

```
[
   {
      "id":3,
      "taskRepositoryID":null,
      "timesheetID":null,
      "timeCategoryID":null,
      "startTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "endTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "duration":0,
      "comment":"some comment"
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "taskRepositoryID":null,
      "timesheetID":null,
      "timeCategoryID":null,
      "startTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "endTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "duration":0,
      "comment":"some comment"
   }
]
```

TypeScript class:

```
export class TestTime {
  id: number;
  taskRepositoryID: any;
  timesheetID: any;
  timeCategoryID: any;
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
  duration: any;
  comment: string;
```

}

How I can parse the json data to array of my class TestTime?

Comment: How are you getting the JSON... with an AJAX request?

Comment: @Fenton, this._timeServcie.getTimeForRange<any>(argumets)
            .subscribe((data: string) => this.result = JSON.stringify(data),
            error => () => {
                console.log("error");
            },
            () => {                             
            });

Comment: Sorry to be a pain - but can we drill one level deeper into that `timeServcie.getTimeForRange` method?

Comment: @Fenton,  public getTimeForRange<T>(objArgument: any): Observable<T> {
        const toAdd = JSON.stringify({ timeRange: objArgument });
        return this._http.post<T>("http://localhost:111/GetTime", toAdd);
    }

Comment: @Fenton I manage to access the data only in the success function in the first block of code which I commented u, but I am not able to access the data outside the success block, any ideas how to be able to access the data outside of the block code? I am parsing it succesfully in the success block but if I want to access the list outside the success block, it's says undefined, which means it's empty..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
let myList:TestTime[]  = JSON.parse(myJson);
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0. This is what I gets when I try it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass a type argument to get back everything typed as you expect:

```
this._timeServcie.getTimeForRange<TestTime[]>(argumets) 
    .subscribe((data: TestTime[]) => //...
```